# ADD CONSTRAINT on date part of a datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date-arithmetic, unique-index

I want to add a unique constraint on multiple columns. Usually, the following script should do the job:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_yourtablename
  ON dbo.yourtablename(column1, column2);
```

How about if columns2 is DateTime and we want to set the constraint only on the date part?
One solution could be using triggers but I need to avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a computed column to virtually store the date part of the datetime column, and use it in the unique index.

```
create table yourtablename (
    column1 int, 
    column2 datetime, 
    column2_dt as convert(date, column2)
);

create unique index uq_yourtablename on yourtablename(column1, column2_dt);
```

Comment: Nice approach. 
I'm getting Column X in table Y is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

Comment: @Kamran: here is a db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=610db892f5b6aea6acc4cee3570989a8. This seems to work fine, even in old SQL Server versions (2014).

Comment: Fixed. not related to this.
How can we exclude null values from the unique index?

Comment: I just needed to add WHERE PaymentReference IS NOT NULL